When to add "-вши" suffix to perfective adverbial participles (gerunds)?
According to wiktionary, "написав" is the "short past adverbial perfective participle" of "написа́ть" while "написавши" is simply the "past adverbial perfective participle" of "написа́ть". It seems that this "short" form is used more often when using perfective adverbial participles. But are the "short" and "not short" forms interchangeable, or is there some rule that dictates when to/not to use the "short" form?
Is "Написавши письмо, Игорь отнес его на почту." just as correct as "Написав письмо, Игорь отнес его на почту."?


But are the "short" and "not short" forms interchangeable, or is there some rule that dictates when to/not to use the "short" form?

-ши is required for reflexive verbs (вернуть > вернув, but вернуться > вернувшись).
For non-reflexive verbs, forms in -ши in modern Russian are perceived as marked (colloquial, dated, or humorous), and are not being used in neutral discourse. They are used in some set phrases and proverbs: снявши голову, по волосам не плачут; не давши слова, крепись, а давши — держись; что имеем, не храним, потерявши — плачем, etc.
In some Russian dialects, forms in -ши were used to form a so called neo-perfect tense: он уехавши "he's gone (somewhere)", она поевши "she has eaten" and so on. In the mainstream language, this paradigm is used in the predicative adverb  выпивши "tipsy, slightly drunk", like in он был выпивши "he was tipsy".
Etymologically, forms in -ши are remnants of the feminine forms of past participles in Old Russian. Their present counterparts survived in Russian as present active adjectival participles in -учи/-ючи: крадучись, играючи, умеючи etc. These forms are also somewhat marked, and are closer in meaning to adverbs than adverbial participles. The exception is the form будучи from быть: it's the only present active adverbial participle that does require the suffix -учи.

Sorry, just wanted to say I love your answers, so deep and professional yet without overwhelming the reader with complicated stuff. Я сам носитель и лингвист (хоть и не по славянским языкам), но лучше бы точно не ответил. Просто класс!

@AndréPolykanine: thank you!

We are talking about деепричастия совершенного вида.
Написав письмо, Игорь отнес его на почту.
Написавши грамоту, князь Игорь отдал ее гонцу.
Can you see the difference?
In modern Russian the majority of verbs form деепричастия совершенного вида with the suffix -в.
Прочитать — прочитав. Написать — написав. Увидеть — увидев.
Прочитавши, написавши, увидевши can be used in some poetic or historical context , proverbs, folklore, etc.
Like in
Что имеем — не храним, потерявши — плачем. Or Несолоно хлебавши. Снявши голову, по волосам не плачут.
In ordinary speech they sound archaic.
But you will never make a mistake using -вши with reflexive verbs, the group is very big, and widely uses this suffix in modern speech.
остановиться — остановившись
задуматься — задумавшись
испугаться — испугавшись.
Some of them can have two forms встретившись (встретясь).
I don't touch upon other suffixes, -а,-я, or -ши.
